# Visual studio update cordova error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

My visual studio 2015 keeps having the following error when updating cordova?

> Android SDK Setup (API Level 23) : The following package(s) were not downloaded: build-tools-23.0.1 android-23 . Please check your internet connection and try again.

Answer (score 1):

I also got the same error. I fixed it by opening **Android SDK Manager** GUI from your installation dir which in my case was `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk` and forcing use of `http` instead of `https` from `Tools > Options` window.

HTH

Sam

Comment: Forgot to mention that I resumed the package installation from Android SDK Manager itself instead of VS.

Comment: I cannot run `SDK Manager.exe`. A window flashed and closed.

Answer (score 0):

VS will install/expect Android SDK in the default location c:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk. If you have another copy of Android SDK in a non-default location (and if it's tools are in the search path) it will cause problems with VS.